# How can I check if a number is descending in c?

Tags: c

How can I check if a number is descending, and have a flag that would indicate yes or no?
Not an array.

In the last loop, *last* or *x* take value 0, and because of that answer is not correct.

```
while(n>1)
    {
        last=n%10;
        x=n/10%10;
        
        if(last>x){
            flag=0;
        }
        if(last<x){
            flag=1;
        }
        n=n/10;
    }
    if(flag==0) printf("0\n");
    else printf("1\n");
```

Comment: `flag=0` -> `flag==0`

Comment: I think you're talking about a number whose digits are descending from left to right e.g. 7321.

Comment: Was `flag == 0` the problem?  Normally when you post code here it would be an exact copy/paste of the code you want us to evaluate.

Comment: thanks, corrected, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you debug the code? Print `last` and `x` at each comparison. Are they what you expected?

Comment: flag == 0 wasn't the problem, i check the code in  code execution(https://pythontutor.com), and in the last loop when there is no available digits  `x` or `last` take value 0

Comment: Change loop to: `while(n>10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isDescending(int n)
{
    bool descending=true;
    
    while(n/10 && descending)
    {
        int d=n%10;
        n/=10;
        descending = d<n%10;
    }
    return descending;
}

int main(void) {
    int test[] = { 123456, 975310 };
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        printf("Descending %d: %s\n", test[i], isDescending(test[i])? "Yes" : "No" );
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Result:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5432KB
Descending 123456: No
Descending 975310: Yes
```